# Most used authentication type in SharePoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, authentication, windows-authentication

Can anyone let me know which is the most widely used user authentication method in SharePoint Servers ?

I found the user authentication methods available in this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such statistics available, which is mostly used.

But as per my information and working with different companies and discussion with sharepoint folks and sharepoint meetings.

Windows authentication (ntlm) is clearly way ahead from everybody.

Another thing I noticed due to o365 saml based authentication(ADFS) also getting popularity.

But this is purely depends on the one,s company's requirement.

Comment: I agree, from experience, Windows Authentication is most common. The only time I've seen other was claims-based for some Army sites. The are a few features that require a different type. Second most used is probably Kerberos. This might be helpful for planning: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee914605.aspx

Answer (score 1):

While Windows Authentication using NTLM is likely the most common, if you're thinking about an implementation I would strongly recommend using Windows Authentication using Kerberos. Kerberos is easy to set up, although it will not work from clients that cannot access the KDC (Domain Controller) and under certain cross-forest scenarios.

Setting up Kerberos involves setting the Service Principal Name on the Domain User running the IIS Application Pool. In this example, the user is CORP\s-web with https://sharepoint.example.com as the URL.'

```
setspn.exe -U -S HTTP/sharepoint.example.com corp\s-web
```

Note that the 'HTTP/' covers both HTTP and HTTPS. If you're using an alternate port you would need to specify `HTTP/sharepoint.example.com:NNNN` where `NNNN` is your port number.

If you have users using SharePoint over the Internet, then I'd suggest you look at implementing Web Application Proxy with Active Directory Federation Services 3.0. Using ADFS 3, you can create a `non-claims aware relying party` which will allow you to continue using Windows Authentication /with Kerberos/ while leveraging WAP for a forms-based login approach. The connection between WAP/ADFS and SharePoint then leverages Kerberos instead of NTLM.

SAML and FBA are the other two options, and I'd imagine SAML edges out FBA due to ease of implementation and ongoing maintenance compared to FBA, but that's simply a guess.

Answer (score 1):

With DOD I mostly see SAML based with some form of ADFS type service